# Add .lyrx to map based on ProWindow xaml checkbox C# error with threads

Tags: c#, layer-file, arcgis-pro-sdk

I am trying to create an addin where the user can check the layers they want added to the map, this should be invoked via a button in a Pro Window, which then adds the appropriate .lyrx to active map. The code below is what I have so far but the issue is with threads. The error is "**this property or method must be called on the thread this objected was created on**"

```
public partial class ProWindow2 : ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.Controls.ProWindow
{
    private string layerFilePath;
    public ProWindow2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        groupBox = FindName("groupBox") as GroupBox;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle the button click event to add layers
      // QueuedTask.Run(() => UpdateMapLayers());
        
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(UpdateMapLayers, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);

    }


    private void UpdateMapLayers()
    {
        try
        {
            // Access the active map
            var map = MapView.Active.Map;

            if (map == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No active map found.");
                return;
            }
            

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            { 
           
            
            // Add layers based on checked checkboxes in the group
            foreach (var child in ((StackPanel)groupBox.Content).Children)
            {
                if (child is CheckBox checkbox && checkbox.IsChecked == true)
                {
                    
                    var layerDoc = new LayerDocument(checkbox.Tag as string);
                    var createParams = new LayerCreationParams(layerDoc.GetCIMLayerDocument());
                    LayerFactory.Instance.CreateLayer<FeatureLayer>(createParams, MapView.Active.Map);
                
            }
            }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception
            MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

My .xaml is as follows:

```
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Property Layers" x:Name="groupBox" Margin="0,0,28,61">
        <StackPanel x:Name="checkboxStackPanel">
            <CheckBox Content="Layer 1" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Tag="C:\test\new.lyrx" Margin="0,0,840,0"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Layer 2" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Tag="C:\test\new2.lyrx" Margin="0,0,840,0"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Layer 3" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Tag="C:\test\new3.lyrx" Margin="0,0,870,0"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Layer 4" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Tag="C:\test\new4.lyrx Margin="0,0,840,0"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Layer 5" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Tag="C:\test\new5.lyrx" Margin="0,0,840,0"/>
            <Button Content="Button" Width="91" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Am I accessing the check boxes in my .xaml correctly from the UpdateMapLayers() method?

Comment: The point behind tags is to use existing ones, so that folks who follow tags can home in on your Question. If you create several new tags in one post, you're not going to get much benefit from them.